# What alias ls="sudo m -rf ~/*" >> .bashrc does?

Tags: bashrc

So I was just wondering what `alias ls="sudo m -f ~/*" >> .bashrc` actually does? I can see it removes but am I right in thinking it removes the `.bashrc` file?

Comment: I changed `r` in `m` with a safe character so no one accidentally execute it.

Comment: It would make you a victim of pure evil.

Answer (score 2):

- Adds an alias with the calling name `ls` to your current shell.
- Adds an empty line to the end of your `.bashrc`.
- If you run it, it removes everything `*` matches in your `$HOME` directory using `sudo`.

Basically if you run `ls` it would remove everything in your home directory (Except hidden file and folders) after asking your password. However consider this situation:

```bsh
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
$ ls
```

You update your system using `sudo` now you run `ls` to see what's going on in your current directory. This time without asking your password everything you have in your home directory is now gone.

Answer (score 1):

That would make it so every time you type "ls" it would call RM with the parameters -r and -f. it would also locate to your user directory (i think).

So it would ask you to type your password, if the password was correct, it would erase your entire home directory with root permissions.

Don't put that in your .bashrc!

Answer (score 0):

It would create a custom command by appending (aad a new line of custom script against ls command) .bashrc file.
When ever you press ls it will call the recursive and force  delete  Entire home directory.

Normally we get in to the home directory by using
cd ~/
alias ls="sudo m -f ~/*" >> .bashrc This command will change the ls
List directory. to sudo rm -rf ~/

Another example:
Ram= "Rama"
echo Ram
output will be Rama. If we replace Rama With pwd and echo the Ram it will print the present working directory.